# Site in Wordpress Multisite can't be accessed after changing primary domain

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress multisite that I recently added a new site to. When I changed the primary domain for this new site I made a spelling error in the top-level domain part of the domain name (ex: .con instead of .com), and I can now, no longer access the site's dashboard as I could before this change. I know about doing a wp search-replace on the database, but I'm not finding that new primary domain change where you might expect (wp_options, wp_posts), or anywhere in the db. However, when I visit the original domain, I get redirected to the newly misspelled one.

Surely...there must be a way to change this domain to the correct one and remedy this without having to recreate the sub site over again.

Comment: I think this is the problem with your domain control, not wordpress

Comment: @Vishwa can you say a little more about this?